# Why is the calculated time returned in the __enter__ method using context manager in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# timing.py
from time import perf_counter

class Timer:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = perf_counter()
        self.end = 0.0
        return lambda: self.end - self.start # Does it not evaluate to 0.0 - self.start???

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.end = perf_counter()

With Timer() as time:
    # do something

print(time())
```

In the above code, according to me, the return statement should be placed in the `__exit__()` method as it hold the true value of the end time.

I know that the `__enter__()` method is called once at the beginning of the `with` block, so it should hold the starting time. Logically it makes sense to me that the `__exit__()`, which is also called once, can calculate the ending time and then return the elapsed time.

The above code gives me the impression that the `__enter__()` method is called twice.

Kindly provide me clarity on what is going on.

Comment: Do you know what `lambda` means?

Comment: `lambda` function calculates the elapsed time and returns it. But why is it not in the `__exit__` method? @user2357112

Comment: Returning a function does not make it do anything. It does only when it is called.

Comment: This question should include a demo of how you’re calling it.  Are you calling the returned lambda as soon as the context is entered?  Or at the end?  Or not at all?  (Entering the context does *not* automatically call the function you’re returning from `__enter__`!)

Comment: What an incredibly convoluted way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value returned by the `__enter__` method is assigned to the `as ...` variable.  So in the example you give, the variable `time` will be assigned the lambda expression.

Lambda expressions are functions.  They are not immediately evaluated.

So at the time your code calls `time()`, both `self.start` and `self.end` have values assigned by `__enter__` and `__exit__`, respectively.  Calling `time()` will calculate and return the difference between the start time and the end time.

Comment: FWIW, doing `return self` in `__enter__` and adding a `__call__` method instead of the `lambda` would provide the same interface but more legible.